# Oracle - View, display in one column value from different columns

Tags: sql, oracle, view

I'm trying to create a view of certain fields from one table. Due to restrictions, the view must be in this format.

Let's call the table Employee. I need the view to display the field Info1 if the value in Category field = A. If the value in Category field = B then the Info2 value is needed instead.

```
Create View Emp as Select name, category, info from 
  (select name, category, info1 from employee where category='A') 
UNION 
  (select name, category, info2 from employee where category <>'A')
```

My understanding is that this can be done with a union, however my view has many fields and the query would be long with a union. Is there another way to achieve the same result? Through DECODE method perhaps?

```
Name   ID   Category    Info1    Info2 </h1>
Max    11   A           VIP      Present 
---
Sandra 22   A           VIP      XXX 
---
Lou    33   B           Regular  XXX 
---
Pat    44   B           VIP      XXX 
---
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want a case statement

```
 Create View Emp as
   Select name, category, 
          CASE WHEN category='A' THEN info1 ELSE info2 END as INFO 
   from employee
```

or you may want a join

```
 Create View Emp as
   Select a.name, a.category, b.info1, c.info2
   from employee a
   join employee b on (a.name, a.category) = (b.name, b.category) and b.category = 'A'
   join employee c on (a.name, a.category) = (c.name, c.category) and c.category <> 'A'
```

or you can stick with the union -- but if you do I suggest union all -- it will be faster.

In any case, what you really want depends on all the requirements you are not telling us.

Don't be afraid to have a long query -- there really is nothing wrong with how many lines a query is -- it can be 100s of lines long and produce a faster output then a smaller query doing the same thing.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I hadn't thought of using the CASE option. I definitely prefer it to the union.
My requirement is simply that, just to display different columns based on a category value. I'll compare the performance between a UNION ALL and the CASE option and if the union produces faster results, I'll go with the UNION ALL. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
Create View Emp
as
  Select name,
         category,
         CASE category WHEN 'A' THEN info1 ELSE info2 END AS info
  from   employee
```